# How to get the file Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have a project on Symfony 4.4 and I use a bundle that needs this ObjectManager. The thing is, the namespace used in the vendor in FOSUser indicates that it needs Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, when in my project I only have Doctrine\Persistence\Object. Since I can't modifiy the file in the vendor, how can I get it to work? How can I get the Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager or tell the FOSUser UserManager to use Doctrine\Persistence\Object instead of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager?
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you rant into [this issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2996).  Bottom line is that FOSUserBundle is not longer being maintained.  Avoid using it if at all possible.  As the issue indicates, a few developers have forked the package and tweaked it to work.

Comment: What if I need to use FOSUser anyway?

Comment: Either fork the package yourself and make the necessary changes or use one of the existing forks.  The Symfony eco-system has done an amazing job of keeping it's core software up to date over the last ten years or so.  Not all third party bundles such as the FOS bundles can say the same.  It's part of the fun of using open source software.  I have always been a bit unsure why FOSUserBundle became so popular.  I tried using it in the early days and found it to be just plain silly.  And quickly moved on.